# What happened to the Blends in Z Nation?

Tags: z-nation

During Season 3 of Z Nation Murphy established a community of Blends, kind of human-zombie hybrids that he has mental influence over created either by his bite or a special inoculation made from his blood, in Spokane. Much of the season focused on the development of this community and Warren's attempt to put a stop to that development and create a real vaccine. The last few episodes switched the focus to the search for Lucy, who was kidnapped by The Man to be delivered to Zona. Murphy left a few of his Blends in charge of his community when the main cast went after Lucy and basically told them to hold down the fort until he got back, but instead he and Warren both ended up in Zona and were fully cured of the zombie virus.

So, what happened to the Blends that Murphy created and their community in the end? Do they even get mentioned again after Season 3? And what effect would it have on them with Murphy being fully cured?

Comment: I only saw the first 2 seasons. I did some google searching, It looks like Season 4 takes place 2 years after the end of S3. And I saw no mention of Blends after S3. I would assume that after Murphy's "Death" at the end of S3 and loss of power the blends fell apart. But would need someone who actually watched the series to confirm if I am right or not.